# How to calculate LXC load average

Tags: linux, lxc

How I can calculate or fetch LoadAverage from LXC container? (/proc/loadavg has load from physical server not from vm)

Any ideas ?

Comment: load is too overrated. I would be more interested in knowing CPU usage.